# Excel sheet copy a particular field in all columns

Tags: excel

Please look at the image attached.

I want to select orange product in all the columns (as some days orange is not found) and draw a graph or copy the data of orange product in any other sheet.

sample issue
[image: sample issue]

Comment: Consolidate the data in a single sheet and apply a simple filter

Comment: Why do you space it out like that? I can see that the date is changing but that is not enough reason to  do like that in my opinion. Keep everything in four columns and it will be much easier later as you can filter it and build pivot tables. The way you do it, everything needs to be done manually.

Comment: @pnuts I saw that too after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should always tabulate data that has related information in the same columns.
Your table should only have the main 4 columns and then just have the data going downwards.
To be able to create a graph the way your data is currently i would suggest the following.
If you want total Quantity you can do a

`=Sumifs($D:$D,$A:$A,"Orange")`

You can then just reuse this formula changing the cell reference to each set of columns 
like so

`=Sumifs($D:$D,$A:$A,"Orange")+Sumifs($E:$E,$H:$H,"Orange")+Sumifs($M:$M,$P:$P,"Orange")`